# Can a script convert website colours to be consistent across multiple devices?

Tags: css, mobile, colors, gamma

I've noticed when checking my site across multiple devices, the colour yellow on the desktop looks orange on another device.

Is there a conversion standard or technique, script or method to convert some colours, or add a filter or any other hack or work around to change the colour across a website depending on device to more closely match particular colours?

Comment: actually this is a good question, I noticed it too, and I think it's some kind of color decoding problem because compared to a fixed color png my BG sometimes shows the same color of it, but in other devices it clearly shows a different color.

Comment: But for that you'd have to first identify what color the device is showing (not what you have specified).. May be hard coding the proper color code based on device identification would do the trick?

Comment: It depends on what color profile is used by the devices/monitors. It's not a browser feature so I don't think you can do this with a js. https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/keeping-colors-consistent.html

Answer (score 0):

you can use the user-agent to detect what device / browser is being used and apply different css or modify through javascript etc. as needed.

heres a link to dynamically load a css file in javascript:

http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/loadjavascriptcss.shtml

EDIT:
This would assume you know which devices / browsers show the colours incorrectly